# How to Pass Decimal Value as Argument Correctly

Tags: c++, decimal, argument-passing

I have this:

```
double myDecimal = static_cast<double>(atoi(arg_vec[1]));
cout << myDecimal << endl;
```

But why when I pass the argument like this:

```
./MyCode 0.003
```

It prints `0` instead of `0.003`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`atoi()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) converts to integer. You want [`atof()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof).

Or you could use [strtod().](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod.html)

Answer (score 3):

atoi() converts to an integer, you want atof(), which converts to a double

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using C++, you can also use stringstreams:

```
istringstream ss(arg_vec[1]);
double d;
ss >> d;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = boost::lexical_cast<double>("0.003");
```